# Is it possible to have 2 profile models using django's AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE

Tags: django, profile, authentication

Is is possible to have 2 models to store extra user details. I ask because I'm currently writing an app which i want to plug into a few existing projects. However all these projects already use a profile model, and my new app needs to extend the user model through the profile model. If it isn't is there a way of extending the currently in use profile model set within AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you just create a field in this other model that has a foreign key to the profile?

So assuming you have an already existent UserProfile model.

```
Class UserProfile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User)
  ...
```

You could extend the UserProfile model by adding a foreign key in your other model, linking to it.

```
Class OtherModel(models.Model):
  profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name="other_model")
  field1 = models.CharField(max_length=15)
  ...
```

And so you can access this other model from the User object:

```
user.get_profile().other_model.field1
```

HTH

Comment: Any idea how to import the user model without knowing the path? Possibly by using django.conf.AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE?