# auth profile module problems with multiple profiles

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

Similar to this question: [Is it possible to have 2 profile models using django's AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634256/is-it-possible-to-have-2-profile-models-using-djangos-auth-profile-module)

But I'm trying to use a django template tag to get what I need.

There are 2 profiles:

```
class Profile1(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, unique=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/users/', null=True, blank=True)
    ... More fields ...
class Profile2(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, unique=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/users/', null=True, blank=True)
    ... More fields ...

AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'profiles.UserProfile'

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    profile1 = models.ForeignKey(Profile1, related_name="profile1")
    profile2 = models.ForeignKey(Profile2, related_name="profile2")
    # Each user can essentially have more than one profile.
```

So how do I grab a the users profile with get_profile() within a template tag?  Ie: If I'm trying to retrieve the user's avatar for a profile...

```
{{ comment.user.get_profile.avatar }}
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: Are you saying a user can have more than one profile instance? Or more than one type of a profile where as each profile will have different attributes?

Comment: Can you explain "doesn't work" a little more? Does it throw an error? Do you not see the output you're expecting? UserProfile doesn't seem to have an avatar field, which seems like it could be causing a problem here.

Comment: @Meitham Each user can have more than one type of profile that has different attributes. (I apologize for the confusion)

Comment: @girasquid There is no error. It does not show the avatar. And to link it : `<a href="{{ comment.user.get_profile.get_absolute_url }}">`... It returns the same page.

Comment: It's not showing an avatar because none of those models have an avatar field - if your avatar was on profile1 for example, you would need to use `{{ comment.user.get_profile.profile1.avatar }}`.

Answer (score 0):

If avator is defined in model `Profile1` then you could do `{{ comment.user.get_profile.profile1.avatar }}`

`get_profile` will return the `UserProfile` instance.

If I was you I would add related_name on the individual profiles like this:

```
class Profile1(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, unique=True, related_name='profile_1')
    ... More fields ...
class Profile2(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, unique=True, related_name='profile_2')
    ... More fields ...
```

Then do `user.profile_1.avatar` rather than going through `get_profile()`.

Comment: I took your advice. And tried both suggestions... Unfortunately it still returns a blank img 
`<a href="{{ comment.user.profile_1.get_absolute_url }}"> <img width=40 height=40 src="{% if comment.user.profile_1.avatar %}{% thumbnail comment.user.profile_1.avatar 60x60 crop %}{% else %}{{ DEFAULT_AVATAR }}{% endif %}" /> </a>`

Comment: Maybe I'm making a mistake somewhere that I can't spot?

Comment: try it through `manage.py shell` there might be no image or get_absolute_url isn't implemented.

Comment: Tried in the shell. Returns all profiles with an avatar. They exist. As for get_absolute_url: I'm not too worried about that at this point. :\

Comment: I don't know if this matters or not. But I can successfully grab the avatar when the `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'profiles.Profile1'` and using `get_profile()`. It's just the `UserProfile` messes everything up. The whole thing is, there are multiple profiles. So I need `UserProfile` to reference all profiles that may be connected to `user`

Comment: @Modelesq which model has the avator field defined in?

Comment: Made the edits to the Profile Models. Profile1 and Profile2 have different avatar fields.